# When the $(\mathbb R,+)$-action defined by the flow of a vector field on a manifold is proper ?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I'm interested in the conditions that a vector field has to satisfy in order for its flow to define a proper action.

Technically, let $\xi$ be a smooth vector field. For each $m\in M$, there is a unique solution $\gamma_m:\mathbb R\mapsto M:\lambda\mapsto\gamma_m(\lambda$) of the differential equation $\frac{d\gamma_m(\lambda)}{d\lambda}=\xi(\gamma_m(\lambda)), \lambda\in\mathbb R$ with initial condition $\gamma_m(0)=m$. The mapping $\varphi_\xi:\mathbb R\times M\mapsto M:(\lambda,m)\mapsto\gamma_m(\lambda)$ is the flow of $\xi$ and defines a left-action of the additive Lie group $G\equiv(\mathbb R,+)$ on $M$.

The action of $\varphi_\xi$ would be said proper if the map $G\times M\mapsto M\times M:(m,\lambda) \mapsto(m,\varphi_\xi(m,\lambda))$ is a proper map.

If anyone has suggestions or references, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a motivation for this question? Do you intend to take the quotient?

Comment: Exactly, I am interested in the quotient of a manifold by the action defined by the flow of a vector field. I convinced myself that the vector field must be nowhere vanishing in order for the action to be free but I am not able to determine conditions in order for it to be proper. Plus, I am not aware of any book or article where it is explicitly discussed.